# Probability distribution function of variable based on two other PDFs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following formula:

$L^2 = C \cdot a \cdot (1- e^2)$

I know that the PDF of $a$ is proportional to $a^\beta$ and the PDF of $e$ is proportional to $e$:

$PDF(a) \propto a^\beta$

$PDF(e) \propto e$

$C$ is a positive real constant, $a \in [0.1, 100]$ and for my case $\beta=-1$ (but could be any real number); finally $e \in [0,1]$. These proptionalities come out a few assumptions about the system that is described by the equation for $L^2$ (which is an equation for the angular momentum $L$, where $a$ is the semi major axis and $e$ is the eccentricity of Kepler orbits in an isotropic distribution)

How is $L^2$ distributed ? I can find an answer by simply sampling from e and a and fitting the histogram of $L^2$, this yields $L^2 \propto -1$, but it isn't immediately clear to me why that should be the case.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please give more detail in your question. Is $C$ a constant? What is the universe of events? Furthermore, it might be easier to have a helpful answer if you show what you have managed to do in this problem. E.g., have you obtained both PDF (and do you need them)?

Comment: Hi @Ertxiem, thanks. If added a few points to the question. What do you mean by "the universe of events" (quite literately it's our universe but I doubt that's what you meant ;))

Comment: I mean what is the domain of numbers you are working with. From what you added, it seems to me that you are using real numbers with $a>0$ and $e \in [0; 1]$ (and $C>0$).

Comment: Of course! Added that ...

Comment: $v a^{-1}$ cannot be the pdf of a random variable with values in $\mathbb R^+$ because $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx \to \infty$

Comment: Thanks @P.Quinto you are right. In fact I cropped the inner boundary of $a \in [0.1, 100]$, where $100 \sim \inf$

Comment: $0.1$ is actually motivated from our observations, but in fact is a bit arbitrary. It would be nice if I could understand how bad this cut is....